# Android spinner does not scroll, why?

Tags: android, scroll, spinner

I have a spinner in my app where you can select categories and sub categories.
It was working perfect in the past but since i did alot of modifications in the app, the spinner does not scroll anymore, not just one spinner, but all spinners in this layout (Drawer menu).

Here's the XML for the right menu drawer that contains the spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:rsb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rightadvancedsearch"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Grey"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="com.chno.v1.Home">


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="16dp">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/AllCat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/query"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="52dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/Blue"
                    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Search"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/GreyDark" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:text="@string/Category"
                    android:textColor="@color/Blue"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:minHeight="40dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/Blue" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/AllCat"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                        android:text="@string/Location"
                        android:textColor="@color/Blue" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView28"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/SelectCity" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
<!--
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/nearby"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/Nearby" />-->

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkNearby"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@string/Nearby" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/currentray"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/defaultRay"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar.RangeSeekBar
                    android:id="@+id/rangeSeekbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    rsb:absoluteMaxValue="100"
                    rsb:absoluteMinValue="1"
                    rsb:singleThumb="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/includeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/city"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/BgLight">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/GreyLight"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:text="Ré-initialiser"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/Orange"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Recherche"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

This is the spinner adapter:

```
package com.chno.v1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * List view
 */

public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemDate> {

private int groupid;
private Activity context;
private ArrayList<ItemDate> list;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public SpinnerAdapter(Activity context, int groupid, int id, ArrayList<ItemDate> list) {
    super(context,id, list);
    this.list = list;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.groupid = groupid;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(groupid,parent,false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    ItemDate item = list.get(position);
    if(item != null) {
        if(item.getType() != null) {
            if (item.getType().equals("sub_category")) {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(item.getImageId());
            }
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(item.getImageId());
        }
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(item.getImageId());
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(item.getImageId());
    TextView textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    textView.setText(item.getText());
    return itemView;
}

public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup
        parent) {
    return getView(position,convertView,parent);
}

}
```

The thing is i can select items from the spinner but i cannot scroll it down for more items.

Here's the code that populates the spinner:

```
        JSONObject result = config.getCategories();
        Iterator<String> iter = result.keys();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String key = iter.next();
            try {
                JSONObject cat = result.getJSONObject(key);
                String category = cat.getString("n");
                int drawable = helper.getCategoryDrawable(Integer.parseInt(key));
                Log.e("" + category, "" + key);
                list.add(new ItemDate("category", category, Integer.parseInt(key), drawable));
                JSONObject subs = cat.getJSONObject("l");
                Iterator<String> it2 = subs.keys();
                while (it2.hasNext()) {
                    String sub_key = it2.next();
                    JSONObject sub_category = subs.getJSONObject(sub_key);
                    String name = sub_category.getString("n");
                    Log.e("FFROM LIST", "" + name);
                    list.add(new ItemDate("sub_category", name, Integer.parseInt(sub_key), Integer.parseInt(key), R.drawable.tool_icon_filter));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSONException", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Spinner sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        SpinnerAdapter adapter=new SpinnerAdapter((Activity) context, R.layout.sub_select_item, R.id.txt, list);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp.setFocusable(true);
        sp.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

How can i solve this? Thanks.

Comment: seems like you are passing a wrong ID while creating a spinner adapter.

Comment: Which one exactly?

Comment: i don't think there's a problem in the JAVA code, because i use the same adapter with another spinner in a another activity and it scrolls perfectly, perhaps there's something wrong in the LAYOUT.